# Invalid property 'books[0]' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'books[0]' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'books[0]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

readingList.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Reading List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/style.css}"></link>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Your Reading List</h2>
<div th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(books)}">
    <dl th:each="book : ${books}">
        <dt class="bookHeadline">
            <span th:text="${book.title}">Title</span> by
            <span th:text="${book.author}">Author</span>
            (ISBN: <span th:text="${book.isbn}">ISBN</span>)
        </dt>
        <dd class="bookDescription">
            <span th:if="${book.description}" th:text="${book.description}">Description</span>
            <span th:if="${book.description eq null}"> No description available</span>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<div th:if="${#lists.isEmpty(books)}">
    <p>You have no books in your book list</p>
</div>



<hr/>
<h3>Add a book</h3>
<form method="POST" action="#" th:action="@{/readingList}" th:object="${books}">
    <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors()}">
    <span class="validationError">
        Please correct the problems below and resubmit.
    </span>
    </div>


    <label for="title">Title:</label>
      <input type="text"  th:field="*{books[0].title}" size="50"/><br/>
      <span class="validationError"
            th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('books[0].title')}"
            th:errors="*{books[0].title}">
          title error
      </span>
    <!--   <input type="text" name="title" size="50"></input><br/>-->


    <label for="author">Author:</label>
    <input type="text" name="author" size="50"></input><br/>
    <label for="isbn">ISBN:</label>
    <input type="text" name="isbn" size="15"></input><br/>
    <label for="description">Description:</label><br/>
    <textarea name="description" rows="5" cols="80"></textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit"></input>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

ReadingListController.java

```
package com.example.readinglist;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/readingList")
public class ReadingListController {

    private static final String reader = "craig";

    private ReadingListRepository readingListRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ReadingListController(ReadingListRepository readlingListRepository) {
        this.readingListRepository = readlingListRepository;
    }


    @GetMapping
    public String readersBooks(Model model) {
        List<Book> readingList = readingListRepository.findByReader(reader);
        if (readingList != null) {
            model.addAttribute("books", readingList);
        }
        return "readingList";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String addToReadingList(@Valid Book book, BindingResult bindingResult, RedirectAttributes attr) {
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            return "error";
        }
        book.setReader(reader);
        readingListRepository.save(book);
        attr.addFlashAttribute("books", book);
        return "redirect:/readingList";
    }

}
```

Book.java

```
package com.example.readinglist;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Data
@Entity
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String reader;
    private String isbn;
    @NotBlank(message = "title cannot be null")
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String description;

}
```

I understand the issue is due to the wrong way to validate the title property at `<input type="text"  th:field="*{books[0].title}" size="50"/>` because the `books` is an array list, not a simple Object. But the question is, I only want to validate the input for the title field, but the passed-in object is an array, how should I do with it? I also check many similar questions but neither of them matched my case.

Comment: I also checked this article: http://forum.thymeleaf.org/I-have-problem-in-binding-the-list-of-objects-contained-inside-a-object-on-the-form-using-thymeleaf-td3525038.html
that's why I tried to use books[0], but still failed

Comment: You can't use a `List` as a backing object.  `books` needs to a property of another object, then you'll be able to use the expression `*{books[0]}`.

Comment: Thanks Metroids. Do you mean Thymeleaf validation does not support using ArraryList? My requirement is quite simple. I just want to make the `book` object property `title`. This example is from the Spring Boot In Action, Craig Walls. I just want to enhance the validation part a little.  Is there any sample code that I could reference? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to use `th:object` and `th:field`, the `th:object` **cannot** be of type `List`, Thymeleaf just doesn't allow for that.  You need a another object (a `BookForm` or something like that), that contains `List<Book> books` as a property of it.

Use that new `BookForm` object as your `th:object` then your `th:field` expressions should work.

An example of this is seen on the Thymeleaf Spring integer example.  You can see that in [this example of dynamic fields](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#dynamic-fields), the [SeedStarter class](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleafexamples-stsm/blob/3.0-master/src/main/java/thymeleafexamples/stsm/business/entities/SeedStarter.java#L35)  has a `List<Row>` and they aren't just using a List as the `th:object`.